# Does not name a type_in make prossess

Tags: c++, boost

I've been trying to compile some codes in windows but I got this error: 'flann_index_t' does not name a type'
where is this error come from?
Can any one help me to fix this?

```
g++ -I. -Iflann/src/cpp -c -o src/main.o src/main.cpp
In file included from ./boost/asio/async_result.hpp:18,
             from ./boost/asio.hpp:20,
             from src/common.hpp:30,
             from src/main.cpp:9:
./boost/asio/detail/config.hpp:367:5: warning: #warning Please define _WIN32_WIN
NT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately.
./boost/asio/detail/config.hpp:368:5: warning: #warning For example, add -D_WIN3
2_WINNT=0x0501 to the compiler command line.
./boost/asio/detail/config.hpp:369:5: warning: #warning Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x
0501 (i.e. Windows XP target).
In file included from src/common.hpp:50,
             from src/main.cpp:9:
src/CBIR.hpp:32: error: 'flann_index_t' does not name a type
./flann/util/matrix.h: In function 'int cbir::main(int, char**)':
./flann/util/matrix.h:75: error: 'flann::uchar* flann::Matrix_::data' is protected
src/main.cpp:39: error: within this context Makefile:43: recipe for target `src/main.o' failed 
make: *** [src/main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: For the first error, do you include the header file where `flann_index_t` is defined? For the other error, you can't call `protected` member functions unless you inherit from the class in question.

Comment: please add cbir.cpp line 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using [flann](https://github.com/mariusmuja/flann), then you need:

```
#include <flann.h>
```

in `CBIR.hpp`.

Comment: @user2618451 You can make the class that calls the `protected` method a `friend`.

Comment: Tnx guys I solved the problem with your helps but as Joachim mentioned I have another problem with protected member!: './flann/util/matrix.h:75: error: 'flann::uchar* flann::Matrix_::data' is protected' How can I fix this now?! as you find out I'm really new in programming!